# How to solve $X'' - \lambda X =0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do we solve stuff like $$\frac{d^2 X}{dx^2} - \lambda X =0$$ when $\lambda = k^2 >0$?

I just want to find the general solution. It is apparently $X=A\cosh (kx) + B \sinh (kx)$ but I don't know where it comes from.

Please help.

Comment: Find two linearly independent solutions, then your solutions span a vector space in which you can find a solution fitting every possible initial condition requirement. Here, $ \cosh(kx) $ and $\sinh(kx) $ are linearly independent solutions, and so any linear combination is also a solution. We can choose the value of $ A, B $ to make the solution fit the initial conditions.

Comment: You probably mean $\frac{d^2 X}{dx^2}-\lambda X=0$. With $-\lambda x$, it turns out that $X$ is a cubic in $x$.

Comment: This is why it is generally NOT  a good idea to write the function as "X" and the variable as "x"- it is to easy to confuse them!  The general solution to $d^2X/dx^2- x= 0$ is a cubic equation.  The general solution to $d^X/dx^2- X= 0$ is Acosh(x)+ B sinh(x).  I would have written the equation as either $d^2Y/dx^2- Y= 0$ or $d^2X/dt^2- X= 0$.

Comment: Yes I did mean that. I wrote it as x in lectures and just looked at the official lecture notes and it was X. How silly of me!!

Comment: @user247327 Just to confirm, the GS can equivalently be written as $$X=Ae^{-k x}+Be^{k x}$$ right? That is what we learned in A Level when the auxillary equation has real and distinct roots.

Comment: Yes, cosh(x) is defined as $\frac{e^{kx}+ e^{-kx}}{2}$ and sinh(x) is defined as $\frac{e^{kx}- e^{-kx}}{2}$ so $Acosh(x)+ Bsinh(x)= A\frac{e^{kx}+ e^{-kx}}{2}+ B\frac{e^{kx}- e^{-kx}}{2}= \frac{A+ B}{2}e^{kx}+ \frac{A- B}{2}e^{-kx}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is wrong, if $X$ is a function of $x$ (Not that $\frac{d^2}{dx} $ denotes the second derivative with respect to $x$). The solution is simple :

Left $X=f(x)$.

$f''(x) = λx \Leftrightarrow f(x) = \int \int λx dx \Leftrightarrow f(x) = \frac{λx^3}{6} + c_1x + c_2 $ Where $c_2$ is an arbitrary constant. That's by assuming that $X$ (capital) is a function and $x$ (small letter) is the variable.